# CMFCPropertyGridCtrl add editable string property

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cmfcpropertygridctrl

I derived a class from `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` to add a simple interface for my needs. I want to add a new string value so I can edit it:

```
void CPropertyGrid::AddString(const char* tag, const char* defaultValue)
{
    COleVariant valueType(defaultValue);
    CMFCPropertyGridProperty *stringProperty = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(tag, valueType);
    stringProperty->AllowEdit(TRUE);
    AddProperty(stringProperty);
}
```

This adds a new string in the property grid, but I can't edit it. Is there another way to make this editable?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if the problem is that I can't select the edit control from the grid or if the value is read only and I can't modify it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notify** value must be set to true to be able to edit values.

---

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What does that mean?  I have looked for a 'Notify' flag and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Joe: When you are in the resource editor editing the window where you put the `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`, click on the `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` and then look in the properties window, you should see an option for Notify true or false.